# Digging a grave vs Digging up a grave

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage

Which of these phrases would be the most gramatically correct? Additionally, in the case of "**climbing a ladder**" and "**climbing up a ladder**", which makes the most sense?

In case this is country specific, I live in the U.S.

Comment: There's a big difference in meaning between *digging a grave* and *digging up a grave*. The "ladder" phrases would fit better in a separate question, though you should look for similar questions first.

Answer (score 7):

They are both correct but have significant differences in meaning.

***Digging a grave*** is creating a hole in order to bury someone.

***Digging up a grave*** is uncovering a previously-buried body.

(As for the ladder question, since climbing normally happens in an upward direction, "climbing a ladder" and "climbing up a ladder" are synonymous; one could argue that "climbing up" is redundant, but there's no grammatical issue with it.)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! This is a perfect answer: it has everything I need and it make sense. Thanks.

Comment: People climb down ladders just as often as they climb up them (unless they jump down). Even though climb alone means go up, climb down means the opposite.

Comment: *previously-buried body*  Assuming that a body was buried in the grave in the first place.  See various plots (see what I did there?) in crime novels.